# Change a Class Property for a specfic Page

Tags: jquery, css

Hello guys I want to know if there is a way to change a class css property for a single page. I have a class `active` and I want to change one of it's css property just for a specfic page. Is there any way to do that

Comment: Yes, you can use `jquery` , `if(window.location.href == "http://example.com/mypage.html"){ $('div.ative').removeClass()}` or `addClass` or `toggleClass`

Comment: @jiff I do not want to remove the class but just change one of it's property

Comment: why don't just use additional class on this page removing/adding needed properties?

Comment: if you want to change a property, you need to override this class, you need toggleClass to ex. `active2`

Comment: another way is: `$('div.active').css({display: 'block'});` or another property.

Answer (score 0):

Just write simple logic for that.

1st define ID as page name

Ex. `Page = 'contact_us'`

then id for that tag will be contact_us

now just get page name from url.

```
$("#"+page_name).addclass('active');
```

Show me your code for more reference

Hope this will work !

Answer (score 0):

*I made two example on Fiddle for better understanding, just uncomment those lines.*

**First Example:**

```js
//if(window.location.href == "http://example.com/mypage.html"){
$('div.Active').css({
 color: 'blue'
});
//}
```

```css
.Active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Active">
some text some text some text some text some text.
</div>
```

**Second Example:**

```js
//if(window.location.href == "http://example.com/mypage.html"){
$('div.Active').toggleClass('NotActive')
//}
```

```css
.Active {
  color: red;
}

.NotActive {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Active">
some text some text some text some text some text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
if(window.location.href == "http://example.com/mypage.html"){     
    $('div.active').css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```